# Population of vector with matrix elements column by column

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is CodeBlocks 16.01.
This is my code:

```
Program Matrix_To_Vector

Implicit none

Integer::i,j
Integer, parameter :: M = 3 , N = 2
Integer, dimension ( M , N ) :: Matrix_0
Integer, dimension ( M*N ) :: Vector_0

! Population of matrix

Do i = 1 , 3

   Do j = 1 , 2

      Matrix_0(i,j) = i+j

   End Do

End Do

Open (15, File = 'Result.txt', Status = 'Unknown', Action = 'Write')

  Do i = 1 , 3

     Write(15,*) Matrix_0(i,:)

  End Do

  Write(15,*) ( Vector_0(i), i =1 , size(Vector_0))

Close (15)

End Program Matrix_To_Vector
```

The result of matrix population is:

```
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

My intention is to make vector `Vector_0` with elements from matrix `Matrix_0`. The size of vector is `M*N`. First element of vector is `(1,1)` from matrix and last is `(3,2)` - i want to do that column by column.
Is there way for doing that with do loops?
The contetn of wanted vector is:
`2 3 4 3 4 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
do j=1,2
 vector_0(3*(j-1)+1:3*(j-1)+3)=Matrix_0(:,j)
enddo
```

of course you could just do

```
vector_0=reshape(matrix_0,shape(vector_0))
```

as well